# how to get count of rows in the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

In google spreadsheets, after typing in a list of items through cells A1 to A7, I went off to another cell and typed the following formula

```
=COUNT(A1:A7)
```

It reports zero, instead of seven.

I've done exactly what [this](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/otherspreadsheets/qt/090808-google-spreadsheets-count.htm) article does, but still not the correct result.

Comment: Would you please give us the exact data you typed in cells? Please pay attention that COUNT function only counts _numeric_ values

Comment: Data is a list of names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620 COUNT function only counts numeric values. Try COUNTA and it should do the job (explained here https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991)